# Rearrange data in two-dimensional array according to transformation from polar to Cartesian coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, coordinate-transformation, polar-coordinates

I have a two-dimensional array that represents function values at positions in a polar coordinate system. For example:

```
import numpy as np

radius = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
angle = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, radius.size)
r_grid, a_grid = np.meshgrid(radius, angle)
data = np.sqrt((r_grid/radius.max())**2
               + (a_grid/angle.max())**2)
```

Here the `data` is arranged in a rectangular grid corresponding to the polar coordinates. I want to rearrange the data in the array such that the axes represent the corresponding Cartesian coordinate system. The old versus new layout can be visualized as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
ax1.set(title='Polar coordinates', xlabel='Radius', ylabel='Angle')
ax1.pcolormesh(r_grid, a_grid, data)
ax2.set(title='Cartesian coordinates', xlabel='X', ylabel='Y')
x_grid = r_grid * np.cos(a_grid)
y_grid = r_grid * np.sin(a_grid)
ax2.pcolormesh(x_grid, y_grid, data)
```

[image: Example]

Here the coordinates are explicitly given and the plot is adjusted accordingly. I want the data to be rearranged in the data array itself instead. It should contain all values, optionally filling with zeros to fit the shape (similar to [`scipy.ndimage.rotate(..., reshape=True)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)).

If I manually loop over the polar arrays to compute the Cartesian coordinates, the result contains empty regions which ideally should be filled as well:

```
new = np.zeros_like(data)
visits = np.zeros_like(new)
for r, a, d in np.nditer((r_grid, a_grid, data)):
    i = 0.5 * (1 + r * np.sin(a)) * new.shape[0]
    j = 0.5 * (1 + r * np.cos(a)) * new.shape[1]
    i = min(int(i), new.shape[0] - 1)
    j = min(int(j), new.shape[1] - 1)
    new[i, j] += d
    visits[i, j] += 1
new /= np.maximum(visits, 1)
ax2.imshow(new, origin='lower')
```

[image: Example attempt]

Is there a way to achieve the transformation while avoiding empty regions in the resulting data array?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr: No, not without changing some conditions of your problem.**

The artefact you are seeing is a property of the transformation.
It is not due to the fixed resolution in angle for all radii.
Hence, it is not due to a wrong or bad implementation of the transformation.
The Cartesian grid simply implies a higher special resolution at these areas as there are resolved points from the polar map.

- The only "clean" way (that I can think of right now) to handle this is to have an adjustable resolution in the polar coordinates to account for the 1/r scaling. (If you input data allows it)
- A somewhat cheating way of visualizing this without the gaps would to randomly distribute them over the gaps. The argument here is, that you do not have the resolution to decide in which bin they were to begin with. So you could just randomly throw them in one which might have been a possible origin and not throw them all in same one (as you are doing right now).
  However, I would like discourage this stronlgy. It just gives you a prettier plot.
  Note, that this is somewhat equivalent to the behaviour of the upper right plot in your question.

Comment: Indeed the problem is decreasing spatial resolution with increasing radius since the angular resolution is fixed. I just tried an approach where the angular data gets interpolated for each radius with density proportional to `1/r` before the transformation to Cartesian coordinates is computed. The results look promising, just a few artifacts around `y = 0` remain, so I'm still looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really give the expected result, but maybe will help you in achieving a solution after some needed correction...

```
import numpy as np

radius = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
angle = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, radius.size)
r_grid, a_grid = np.meshgrid(radius, angle)
data = np.sqrt((r_grid/radius.max())**2
               + (a_grid/angle.max())**2)


def polar_to_cartesian(data):
    new = np.zeros_like(data) * np.nan
    x = np.linspace(-1, 1, new.shape[1])
    y = np.linspace(-1, 1, new.shape[0])
    for i in range(new.shape[0]):
        for j in range(new.shape[1]):
            x0, y0 = x[j], y[i]
            r, a = np.sqrt(x0**2 + y0**2), np.arctan2(y0, x0)
            data_i = np.argmin(np.abs(a_grid[:, 0] - a))
            data_j = np.argmin(np.abs(r_grid[0, :] - r))
            val = data[data_i, data_j]

            if r <= 1:
                new[i, j] = val

    return new

new = polar_to_cartesian(data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(new, origin='lower')
```

[image]

EDIT:
Modified using `np.arctan2` according to the suggestions of OP.

Comment: In order to obtain the correct angular dependency `np.arctan2` should be used, but in any case this introduces huge discrepancies towards the edges of the Cartesian coordinate system. In reality there are no data points but since this approach just considers the nearest available data point it gets filled while it shouldn't.

Comment: @a_guest indeed it just considers the closest value. It's basically doing a nearest neighbor interpolation. If you would need a more advanced interpolation I guess it gets much more complicated since the interpolation should be done in the radial space. Maybe it would be a possibility to use `skimage.transform.resize` to upsample the polar image by a given factor and using a bilinear o bicubic interpolation and then use this approach to do the transform. You would end up with a more accurate transformation.

Comment: @a_guest limiting the radius to 1 could solve the borders issues?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the Cartesian array, transforming each grid point to polar coordinates and approximating the function value by interpolation from your polar grid data. You may still want to leave the corner regions blank though, for lack of close enough data.

I don't think there is a better way, unless of course you have access to the original function.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, these interpolated grid points will be position "between" the present grid points. Therefore, it is undecidable from which grid point they came from. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes, when you transform one of the Cartesian grid points to polar coordinates it will in general be somewhere in between four of the polar grid points. So you assign it a function value by taking an average of the function values of those four grid points, weighted according to the distance. That's what I meant by interpolation.

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation

Comment: Ah, alright. But this only makes the individual points "larger" as it distributes it over four points which helps for low values of r only.
This will still result in a star shaped pattern for larger values of r

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that. With the method outlined above, you can calculate a distinct estimate of the function value for every single Cartesian grid point.

Comment: I'm not sure if an interpolation of the Cartesian data will help, at least the choice of quadrilateral corners is not trivial since the density of available data points decreases with increasing distance from the center. For that reasons I think that interpolation in polar space is better since it comes down to a simple one-dimensional linear interpolation.